# front end development Mithril.js

Tags: javascript, html, mithril.js

how can we render elements of a 2-D array to data table using mithil.js??

For table:

```
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];
```

my code was:

```
function view_table(){
    var result="<table>";
    for(var i=start-1;i<start+outof-1;++i)
    {
        result+="<tr>";
        result+="<td>"+(i+1)+"</td>";
        for(var j=0;j<dataSet[i].length;++j)
        {
            result+="<td>"+dataSet[i][j]+"</td>";
        }
        result+="</tr>";
    }
    result+="</table>";
    return result
}
```

But all the columns of the given array within a range of rows ar'nt being rendered to their respective columns in the table.

Comment: are you using only javascript ot any any library like jquery?

Comment: only javascript framework mithil.js

Answer (score 2):

I see that you've already answered your own question, but here's a different way you could approach it.

```
m.mount(document.body, {
    view() {
        return m("table",
            m("thead",
                m("tr",
                    m("th", "Name"),
                    m("th", "Designation"),
                    m("th", "Location"),
                    m("th", "ID #"),
                    m("th", "Join Date"),
                    m("th", "Salary"),
                )
            ),

            m("tbody",
                dataSet.map((row) => m("tr",
                    row.map((cell) => m("td", cell))
                ))
            )
        );
    }
});
```

I also put together a [live example of this code](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4AbhgBOAAgAmGYhgDKMYtIC805AB000-VunaQAFQgBzGDIByEAB71jFIyCUBPOIyzSAgpOqEEIzUxE4uAKKyEGgARgCukuaEYcYArAAsAEwAjCkgmQAM2dkA9AXpJZmpeQAkAMyFFAAcBQXG0gC6FLoGhsYA4lKSqmoA6tGMknB5PtR0cQwYDHkmtADWbrR5TVmZeYXFZQDsldWULjXZRwUUR6ltIJ3degbILj5wJPTSAMK0dnkAFILCC0GQmGABNAQagYKC+OLEQhgvJKJbSABikiW1AgcDoeWyqQAbHtzsZCgUAJxlUrZMnOYw1JrEiitB5PHqvFw-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-RQGClbSPlQTELAqIeF4cC+LIWDRF2TaSw+GdDiOhJLt9S3qeUFG1JkQEM81TOFtiJ4wND-TDDqlnWbZwwOU5Lkbw+NskwrqSpNTCs-tklEhXVdPLhX89V8YcEQNIEGgolD5e1YSFw-Co3jUmvqLyRpSKZEYo7YulR-paSuB7SuWsQAxThsQRgvw4SyD7CWPIaoNS10VDgBgDcxoTR7P2Ie2djQ1UXBTUoE8b403SOXPSYNWKDgSK-Asu4EYPhDmHFGUhTaY2kDHGEcdE4ZVTunchWcBYPmJESaiF8J7ElOLUPyzDPbgzYhgeAUhpAADUcQwDyF7YYABaNEsAO5KAGkNSQ94XCD1kdsR0DwlqHEpqFVkTCtGsRVHXDu5ZDr4ysZeD4N5PB3lRAhOGPCXC5xngXKBhRahq2BiwheXonKihhKZCC2BaCfx5IEfh4Q7CQkRBADUIjUpiJkIncIUipZFVtmkI45MAo0ivsXdMFBKRbQQa1QYYhojSEBLQNw6UcFiXwQfCIU0DTeWNE0JomR5wUiKJRK06zahUmXKkO4QztHIOhGAOOe0ljmHOpdFsN0xbDAlqEzGGB7EmPfDPEuF8emeKUUyOohzgb3GOaxIsTBDp6FGDlK2m8bJ2V3s5OG8ynoyRevJN8D46YVW-IcIucZp7-maMCx+iCObXWkGvTix9jB8PDklCSGFzaiPSg0n4SVmkPmkmZF8Cl9hzRVpsnpq1ihpPuIMklrUlDIjiNIWsAYgyC1uddeEJsMZOXwlGbYTQqRfMFXQqqfyQCXGJE6B+zFEE6wCCWeyW5AxwHeQ+VCl0myYTbJCHCeEpKxJXvsI4xJdX5CKHQ1RBQNlGqpDpdImSn6uDiGsThCQ1jFOfrMrUyKCatOpSaJoDRVIUUqGGy4VF4ESu0WY+AdBUHSALFIZuIwViQkINCWE8IfCImRPjI+OcXQwO+XQ1Ixx0xMPFea4Z8E9B-AcTATmDbsDEPGumrlsl0XvQpCydxyjfrQOngCkto7tGo0YDBDKcxsTxOMF7IpxBLEXg7nAOxw0gHTWWQ+NZUbaFK2pOtM0bJiX7tYgAVWhMQaGBZESnmNoItVWM1Q4xhZy56PKMUuFSGVQ1lJulWi-XVdJGicy6A6AAbl0LoLA+AsChmIPHYq1A4iEOIPgGI+43DOGAFyUZ-Z44p2kGxliwxiAJD0FgeOxhFAxBbpQKK+hhOicICQpwUmDAyZAMQNyinejKaROnLgxgU6sN6NJkTKnQEuFg5bDCNY9PqaU0ZrTLTYTNks-pgzmmTPGFrCqaQABiXTzmNO2bc0g2gYy4KMF89ZwzsnzxQCkAjKzLFehpwS9IeLBmjDJc00x2QPDrPyEUCoBjWBXnx3jnuPs3H1AAD5pCabU8l3oZXyPFfjulMUFXquadIc4VrUAU5JbS-oPrin+sGBTsRl4rBdCsDG2wDgIBMA4DwPgag15KA0HoEe0QPA2BdBALhNASakCoHm1wPA3ckQCnIFQBI5AeAkGIIqOAiASglAWIqNY5hlu0CwCUc7hBLsAAFsj4GB6ov7l38D8DWyB7UeAoesA6KwIAA).

Comment: on line 51:9 comma has to be removed for it to render

Comment: Only in old browsers that don't support modern ecmascript, it's totally valid to have dangling commas like that.

Comment: I use qutebrowser for day-to-day. And Google Chrome to test your fiddle. Didn't render in either until I removed the comma

Answer (score 0):

i discovered the way to do this.. and the code for this lies here as under..

```
function view_table(){
    var rows=[]
    var col=[]
    col.push(m("td","name"))
    col.push(m("td","designation"))
    col.push(m("td","location"))
    col.push(m("td","id no."))
    col.push(m("td","date of joining"))
    col.push(m("td","salary"))
    rows.push(m("tr",{style:"font-size:150%;background-color:orange;color:white;font-weight:bold"},col))
    for(var i=start-1;i<start+outof-1;++i)
    {
        for(var cols=[],j=0;j<dataSet[i].length;++j)
        {
            cols.push(m("td",{style:"font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;color:orange"}, dataSet[i][j]))
        }
        rows.push(m("tr", cols))
    }
    return m("table",{style:"border:1px solid orange;text-align:center;width:100%;"}, m("tbody", rows))
}
```

Comment: The answer by @Tivac is way more managable. All that is left is to add styles. The usage of higher-order array functions is way more efficient than loops used in your solution